# Does GDPR's physical address rule apply to my real world hobby art group?

Tags: gdpr

I run an art group (in the UK) that meets up every other month to give feedback on each others' work. To share the meeting dates and to share the work we're giving feedback on that month, I have an email list.

From looking at other questions on this site (and elsewhere) it looks like I do need to be compliant with GDPR. This is fine for signing up and unsubscribing, but it looks like I'm also required to tell people a physical address.

This is a hobby group, not a business, so as I understand it, I'd need to do one of the following:

1. Pay for a PO box address to use out of my own pocket.
2. Use my home address.

Are there any other options? Or have I misunderstood and as a hobby group do I not need to supply an address?

Note: In case this is relevant, no money is involved - the group is open to everyone, there's no sign up fee, and we meet in public spaces like cafes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GDPR only has an exception for purely personal or household activities which does not seem to cover your hobby group. You're therefore right that you would have to comply.

What the GDPR does not have is an obligation to publish your *address*. Instead, the information requirements per Art 13 require you only to provide your *identity and contact information* as a controller. What this means precisely is up to the data protection agency in your country.

I think your obligations can be satisfied by providing your real name and email address.

Comment: The reason I thought the address was needed was due to Mailchimp's requirements - they say an address is required by law. Since you posted your answer, I looked into it further - as explained here: https://mailchimp.com/help/anti-spam-requirements-for-email/, it's actually US anti spam laws that require this, not GDPR. So I just can't use Mailchimp (or any other company based in the US) to collect email addresses. (Other countries require a physical address too, but the UK does not at the moment for non-companies). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Amon, see my answer... GDPR does not apply to Natural Persons as Controllers, yet members or an organization who knowingly breached the Law and in such circunstances, it is not GDPR (with exception of some member states... it will be a civil sue...

Answer (score 0):

"... I run an art group (in the UK)..."

Are you an individual person who has launched such an initiative or is there an organization at play?

As per ruled under GDPR Article 13 (and opposite to Amon' feedback) it is never your identity and contact as a Natural Person that must be provided, yet the Organization/ Club/ company (even where one speaks of Single-Member Companies).

GDPR does not "view" Human beings as Controllers, yet Organizations... careful with such mistakes...

Let me know first if you act on your own as a person or if there is an organization.

Comment: The controller can very well be a natural person. This is explicitly included in the Art 4 definition of a controller: “‘controller’ means the **natural** or legal person, public authority, agency or other body […]”. The controller is always the legal entity making the decisions. So unless this hobby group is structured as a non-profit, that's going to be OP themselves.